# C# - get data between dates

Tags: c#, sql-server

The SQL database I am trying to reach has the following columns and their types (as displayed in the "design" window in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio):

timestamp : Datetime (for example : 2017-05-15 08:53:55.000)
price : Single               ,             etc.

I want to send to select all the prices where their timestamp is between now and yesterday, for example. Even though i would like an example for a month too.

My code looks like this:

```
string query = "SELECT price FROM table WHERE  timestamp>=@now AND timestamp<=@yes);";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@now", DateTime.Now);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yesterday", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));
```

But my reader returns empty, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please tag properly.  MySQL is not SQL Server.

Comment: And `@yes` <> `@yesterday`

Comment: Why don't you use `GETDATE()` instead of passing `@now`?

Comment: @Eric understand, thanks.

Comment: @TabAlleman thanks

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto can u explain?

Comment: GETDATE is a built-in function that returns you the current datetime of the database server, you can use that instead of passing the now parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `BETWEEN`, also Yesterday is less than Today:

```
SELECT price FROM table WHERE timestamp BETWEEN @yesterday AND @now
```

Answer (score 1):

You have your dates the wrong way around, try this instead:

```
SELECT price FROM table WHERE  timestamp >= @yes AND timestamp <= @now;
```

Comment: You should also add that `@yes != @yesterday`. Otherwise this is just as broken

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto  Was that really worth a downvote?  There are clearly several things wrong with the code in the question, though per the question it is actually running.  This would suggest that this is simply a badly transposed snippet aiming at a minimal example.  My answer shows what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

You have the @now and @yes reversed, currently it is saying timestamps greater than now and less than yesterday.